# how to slowdown the pyspeech voice and make it more clear

Tags: python, text-to-speech

When i use the speech.say() for pyspeech in python it goes a little fast and is hard to understand. Is there a way to slowdown the speech,make it more clear and change it from female to male? I am using python 2.7.

Comment: The pyspeech web site indicates that the library is no longer being maintained, and I can't see anything in the instructions about changing the speed of speech, though that might be controlled through the OS speech interface.

Comment: I'll give it a try to see if that is the case.

Comment: it seems to not be the os speech interface

Answer (score 1):

Try [PyTTS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyTTS/3.0) instead, it gives you much more control over text-to-speech.

Comment: I downloaded the .exe but it requires python 2.5 is there away around this?